# Do Bundles take precedence over Routing?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-mvc-routing, bundling-and-minification

If I have a Bundle such as:

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/foo/bar").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/foo.js"));
```

And a Route such as:

```
routes.MapRoute(
  "Foo", // Route name
  "foo/bar",
  new
  {
     controller = "Foo",
     action = "Bar"
  });
```

Which one will take precedence?

Will the browser return the `ScriptBundle` or the `ActionResult`?

Comment: what do you mean by browser returning scriptBundle or ActionResult

Comment: @VikramBabu Will it return `foo.js` or the action `Bar`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you [read this post](http://forums.asp.net/post/5012037.aspx), it has been suggested that the bundle route (url) will take priority:

> Clearly the default route with /content/css path matches the css action but the bundling framework will override the http handler.

The post also recommends the convention of prefixing "bundle" to all bundle paths. For example:

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundle/foo/bar").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/foo.js"));
```

The post referenced above is linked in [this tutorial](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/bundling-and-minification), which has a section near the bottom called "Bundle Considerations" which might be of interest.